# How to get first parent of span that is a <p> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, parent

As per [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.2/Traversing/parents) says:

> Find all parent elements of each span
> that is a paragraph.

How to get the first one that matches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("span").parents("p:first")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by *first parent* the one that is *closest* to the element, you can  use [Traversing/closest](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest):

```
$(selector).closest('p');
```

Comment: good psychic abilities. (this doesn't answer the question, but is what the asker wanted)

Comment: Haha.. thats funny. +1 for ESP

Answer (score 1):

jQuery returns such results in an array. Have you tried using [0] after the query. $("span").parents("p")[0]. This would give the first parent.

Answer (score 0):

`$("span").parents("p :first")`